# How can I template my print function on std::ostream?

Tags: c++

So far, I have a function print:

```
template < char Sep = ' ', class... Args >
void print(Args&&... args)
{
    ([](Args&& arg)
        {
            std::cout << arg << Sep;
        }(std::forward<Args>(args)), ...);

    std::cout << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    print("a", 'b', 3, 4.0, 5.0f, true);
}
```

I want to template it on std::ostream so that I can print to the buffer I want but I am struglling. Here is what I tried (I have put errors as comment in the code):

```
//Error: a nontype parameter may not have class type
template < std::ostream os, char Sep = ' ', class... Args >
void print(Args&&... args){ /*omitted code */ os << arg << Sep; }

int main()
{
    print("a", 'b', 3, 4.0, 5.0f, true);
}
```

I though maybe I could use a class to work-around the problem:

```
template < class Buffer >
class Printer
{
public:
    void Set(Buffer* buff)
    {
        this->buff = buff;
    }

    //Error: the usage of 'Printer<std::ostream>::buff' requires the compiler
    //to capture this but the current default capture mode does not allow it
    template < char Sep = ' ', class... Args >
    void operator()(Args&&... args)
    {
        ([](Args&& arg)
            {
                (*buff) << arg << Sep;
            }(std::forward<Args>(args)), ...);

        std::cout << '\n';
    }

private:
    Buffer* buff;
};

int main()
{
    Printer<std::ostream> print;
    print.Set(&std::cout);
    print("a", 'b', 3, 4.0, 5.0f, true);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an ordinary template argument and pass the stream as parameter to the function:

```
#include <iostream>


template <typename stream, char Sep = ' ', class... Args >
void print(stream& out,Args&&... args)
{
    ([&out](Args&& arg)
        {
            out << arg << Sep;
        }(std::forward<Args>(args)), ...);

    std::cout << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    print(std::cout,"a", 'b', 3, 4.0, 5.0f, true);
}
```

If only `std::ostream`s are ok you need not make it a template, but simply use an `std::ostream&` argument. The standard library makes use of inheritance only sparingly, but for streams there are base classes that can be used when you want to use standard streams.

---

PS: As pointed out by MarekR you do not need the lambda. The function is simpler like this:

```
#include <iostream>


template <typename stream, char Sep = ' ', class... Args >
stream& print(stream& out,Args&&... args)
{
    return ((out << args << Sep) , ...) << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    print(std::cout,"a", 'b', 3, 4.0, 5.0f, true);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I see I missed lambda capture in my second attempt. So many things to remember.

Comment: @fbiopen_up thats not things to remember. I made the mistake myself, then read the compiler error and fixed it. Please include the compiler error in questions about a compiler error. I admit that I ignored your second example, because on first sight it looked too complicated and it isnt clear from the question whats the problem with it

Comment: why use of lambda? This is [simpler and cleaner](https://godbolt.org/z/qe6rT3aGG).

Comment: @fbiopen_up fwiw heres the fixed example: https://godbolt.org/z/WGna53e63. However, it is not nice that the constructor leaves the member uninitialized and `Printer<std::ostream> print; print("a", 'b', 3, 4.0, 5.0f, true);` dereferences an uninitialized pointer.

Comment: @MarekR i tried to change as little as possible on OPs code. If you don't mind I'll add your code to this answer

Comment: why have it return `stream&` instead of `void` ?

Comment: @fbiopen_up so you can chain it: `print(std::cout, 1,2,3).print(std::cout, "foo");`

Comment: std::cout does not have print function. But I see what you mean. It works with `<<` . Thats weird but also cool